# Odoo: some modules could not be started

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, odoo, odoo-10

I get the following warning in my browser console from web.assets_common.js.
This only occurs when I'm not logged in so it seems like it's trying to load dependencies that shouldn't be loaded.

This warning also came out of nowhere as I didn't have it before, but now all of the sudden I do. I'm running Odoo 10.0 community edition on a vps.

It only seems to happen with the custom themes as well. If anyone has an idea on how I could fix this. thanks in advance.

console log:

```
warning: Some modules could not be started 
Missing dependencies:    ["web_editor.snippets.options"] 
Rejected modules:        ["website_portal"]0: "website_portal"length: 1__proto__: Array(0) 
Non loaded modules:      ["theme_common.s_progress_bar"]
```

Csv installed modules:

```
"id","auto_install","create_uid/id","create_date","icon","write_uid/id","write_date","sequence"
"base.module_crm","False","","","/crm/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:27:13","5"
"base.module_mail","False","","","/mail/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:25:33","25"
"base.module_website","False","","","/website/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:23:07","50"
"base.module_auth_crypt","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_auth_oauth","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-10-02 12:55:30","100"
"base.module_auth_signup","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:05","100"
"base.module_base","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_base_action_rule","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:11","100"
"base.module_base_import","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:21:37","100"
"base.module_base_setup","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_bus","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_fetchmail","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:15","100"
"base.module_portal","True","","","/portal/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:43","100"
"base.module_report","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:25:43","100"
"base.module_resource","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_sales_team","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:18","100"
"base.module_snippet_google_map","False","","","/snippet_google_map/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:23","100"
"base.module_snippet_latest_posts","True","","","/snippet_latest_posts/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:27:23","100"
"base.module_theme_common","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_theme_opus","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_utm","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_web","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_web_calendar","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_web_diagram","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_web_editor","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_web_kanban","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_web_kanban_gauge","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_web_planner","True","","","/web_planner/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:21:27","100"
"base.module_web_settings_dashboard","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:21:39","100"
"base.module_website_animate","False","","","/website_animate/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-20 18:43:21","100"
"base.module_website_crm","True","","","/website_crm/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:27:25","100"
"base.module_website_form","False","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_website_mail","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_website_partner","False","","","/website_partner/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:01","100"
"base.module_website_portal","False","","","/website_portal/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-23 22:44:02","100"
"base.module_website_theme_install","True","","","/website_theme_install/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:23:17","100"
"base.module_web_tour","True","","","/base/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2018-02-24 11:24:32","100"
"base.module_calendar","False","","","/calendar/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:38","130"
"base.module_website_blog","False","","","/website_blog/static/description/icon.png","base.user_root","2017-09-19 20:26:48","140"
```

Comment: Can you send us the list of installed modules ?

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET Sorry for the late reply. I added a list of the installed modules.

Comment: Did you modify/add any JS file before sowing this error? if yes rever/remove it and try again.

Comment: @KbiR I did not modify anything before I got the error, still no idea what caused it. It is only occurring when I'm not logged in, when I'm logged in I don't get the error.